# XAMPP WIndows VHOST allways directing to localhost

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, vhosts

Today i tried to configure a VHOST for my new Web Project but i encountered a problem i wasn't able to resolve... not even with the help of StackOverflow....

I configured my "httpd-vhosts.conf" as mentioned in a lot of tutorials i've read by now and also set up my host file just as mentioned in the tutorials...

I also checked if my vhost file is includes by the apache httpd.conf (it is)

So here are my configs:

VHOST:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@.testsite.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Projekte\GamePlay_dev"
    ServerName gameplay.localhost
    ServerAlias www.gameplay.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

HOSTS:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       gameplay.localhost
```

And yes i already restarted my server... i even restarted the whole pc, just to make sure...

Comment: My hosts file is `# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
 192.168.1.? www.mywebsite` i.e the actual ip address is used and I retain www.

Comment: You do have **`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`** uncommented in your hosts.conf (obviously pointing where your vhosts file is)

Comment: Yes I do include the vhosts.conf as mentioned above

Comment: In my working (with multiple sites) vhosts, I don't use ServerAlias at all, and the server name is with www I also don't use .localhost (not sure if this will make any difference). Will drop my vhosts in as an answer.

Comment: Just noticed your slashes in second document root are backslashes \ as opposed to forward slashes / (can't recall if it matters, but I it might)

Comment: the backslashes shouldn't make a difference. At work we use the same way to define a vhost and it just works...
will try it without the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, here's a working vhosts that I have :-

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/mt"
     ServerName www.mt.flnet.org
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/mt">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/trishandmike"
     ServerName www.tandm.flnet.org
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/trishandmike">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/Judggle"
     ServerName www.JudggleCopy.flnet.org
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/Judggle">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/mjt"
     ServerName www.mjt.flnet.org
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/mjt">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/ShopWise"
     ServerName www.ShopWise.flnet.org
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/ShopWise">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On pc's on the LAN I have my hosts file as (*note some are redundant as I was running two apaches an different machines and haven't properly tidied up*):-

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    192.168.1.2 www.trishandmike.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.AIPCStudentconnect.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.zonemike.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.tristen.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.csacalc.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.ocportal.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.flwgtest.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.judggle.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.mt.flnet.org # on 2nd box running later Apacahe etc
    192.168.1.2 www.tandm.flnet.org # on 2nd box running later Apacahe etc
    192.168.1.2 www.JudggleCopy.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.mjt.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.judgements.flnet.org
    192.168.1.2 www.shopwise.flnet.org
```

You do have a static IP address for the PC running Apache?

Another difference is that I'm use WAMP. I do know that the supplied aliases caused me some hassle with the later version of WAMP. Check if you are pointed to an alias file e.g. something like `Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"` in your hosts file. I think I deleted an offending file from here.